# Mark Report everytime it prints (preview) in JasperSoft iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, adempiere

Is it possible to mark a report based on the times we click `Preview`?

For example, if we `preview` the report once, it will show `1`.

If we preview the report twice, it will show `2`.

I am using Adempiere and would like to put the report inside the window. So, when I click 'Print' once, it will show `1`, the same when I click Print for the second time it will show `2`, etc.

Any suggestion will be useful :)

Comment: this has to be handled in the server side. When ever user clicks on `preview` update the count of it and send it a parameter to iReport.

Comment: @ManiDeep what function can I use to update the count of it ?

Comment: sorry no idea about adempiere

Answer (score 0):

There is a field in the **AD_Process** table called **Statistic_Count** which function is to store how many times the process has been run.

What I would do is to pass the value of that field as a parameter to the report, so you can print it.

In the process parameter you could add a new numeric parameter called **PreviewTimes** and in the **DefaultValue** field set something like:

```
@SQL=SELECT statistic_count FROM AD_Process WHERE AD_Process_ID = @AD_Process_ID@
```

Then, in the Jasper Report you receive that number and include it.

Hope it helps.